# svnrdump hits a svn precommit hook - how can I resolve

Tags: svn, edit, dump, svnadmin

My company is merging a number of svn repositories.

With svn 1.7 we're using "svnrdump dump --incremental --revision START:STOP SOURCE_URL > patch.dump" to download the contents of the old repository.

And "svnrdump load NEW_URL < patch.dump" to upload to the new repository.

But I've hit a snag. Our IT have setup a number of pre-commit hooks. One mandates at least 10 characters in the comment.

I've found a commit with no comment & no author (Not sure how that is possible).

Hence I get an error

```
svnrdump: E165001: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
Internal failure while executing hook in repository, */svn/code/path*.  This will
require an administrator to correct.  Please file a case using SRM.

Error:
'svnlook info' call failed: get_info() failed: insufficient/invalid output:
*myid*
 2013-07-25 08:02:59 -0700 (Thu, 25 Jul 2013)
 0
```

How can I resolve this? Is it possible to edit patch.dump? i.e. To assign an author & comment? Do I have to involve my IT department?

I could load the surrounding revisions & manually commit an svn diff of the troublesome revision. But I was hoping to stick with svnrdump.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. I identified the revision number that caused the problem & manually updated the old repository to set an author & appropriate comment.

This can easily be done from TortiseSvn & I assume you can set the same properties from the command line.

On TortiseSVN choose

1. Show Log
2. Right click the revision and choose "Edit author"
3. Right click the revision and choose "Edit log message"